# Integrality for group schemes over a discrete valuation ring.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, group-schemes

In [this note](https://virtualmath1.stanford.edu/%7Econrad/mordellsem/Notes/L13.pdf), there is the following theorem:

[Theorem 4.4] Let $\mathscr{G}$ be a separated $R$-group scheme of finite type
such that its open relative identity component $\mathscr{G}^0$ is semi-abelian,
and assume that its generic fiber $A$ is an abelian variety.  The natural map
$f:\mathscr{G}\rightarrow N=N(A)$ is an open immersion.

where $R$ is a discrete valuation ring.

Under the hypotheses, the author concluded that both $\mathscr{G}$ and $N$ are integral $R$-schemes at the end of page 12. I don't understand why $\mathscr{G}$ is.

Comment: The Néron model is smooth over $R$ by definition. Hence $G$ is flat over $R$. But then $G$ must be integral because $A$ is integral. See Prop. 4.3.8 p. 137 in Liu's book "Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves".

Comment: The Néron model is integral by the same result.

Comment: @DamianRössler Thank you!